# How to remove spaces before pattern and after it in python with regex?

Tags: python, regex

**Problem:**
I have a list of strings and I need to get rid of whitespaces before and after substring that looks like `'digit / digit'`. Been stuck on this for quite a while and still don't understand how to fix itI will appreciate any help.

**Sample input:**

```py
steps = [
'mix butter , flour , 1 / 3 c',
'sugar and 1-1 / 4 t',
'vanilla'
]
```

**Expected output:**

```py
[
'mixbutter,flour,1 / 3c',
'sugarand1-1 / 4t',
'vanilla'
]
```

**My approach:**

```py
steps_new = []
for step in steps:
    step = re.sub(r'\s+[^\d+\s/\s\d+]','',step)
    steps_new.append(step)
steps_new
```

**My output:**

```py
[
'mixutterlour 1 / 3',
'sugarnd 1-1 / 4',
'vanilla'
]
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
steps = ['mix butter , flour , 1 / 3 c', 'sugar and 1-1 / 4 t', 'vanilla']
steps_new = [re.sub(r'(\d+\s*/\s*\d+)|\s+', lambda x: x.group(1) or "", x) for x in steps]
print(steps_new) # => ['mixbutter,flour,1 / 3c', 'sugarand1-1 / 4t', 'vanilla']
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/w1ecQT).

The `(\d+\s*/\s*\d+)|\s+` [regex](https://regex101.com/r/eFjmIX/1) matches and captures into Group 1 sequences of digits + zero or more whitespaces + / + zero or more whitespaces + digits (with `(\d+\s*/\s*\d+)`), or (`|`) just matches one or more whitespaces (`\s+`).

If Group 1 participated in the match, the replacement is an empty string. Else, the replacement is the Group 1 value, i.e. no replacement occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all spaces and then insert spaces to correct places `(\d)/(\d)`:

```py
import re

steps = ["mix butter , flour , 1 / 3 c", "sugar and 1-1 / 4 t", "vanilla"]

for step in steps:
    x = re.sub(r"(\d)/(\d)", r"\1 / \2", step.replace(" ", ""))
    print(x)
```

Prints:

```
mixbutter,flour,1 / 3c
sugarand1-1 / 4t
vanilla
```

Comment: Just FYI: here, you assume there are always a single space on both ends of a slash enclosed with digits.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this lookaround based solution to get this in just a single regex:

```bash
(?<!/)[ \t](?![ \t]*/)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zdW7S/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!/)`: Assert that previous character is not `/`
- `[ \t]`: Match a space or tab
- `(?![ \t]*/)`: Assert that next position doesn't have a `/` after 0 or more spaces

**Code:**

```py
import re
 
arr = ["mix butter , flour , 1 / 3 c", "sugar and 1-1 / 4 t", "vanilla"]
 
rx = re.compile(r'(?<!/)[ \t](?![ \t]*/)')
 
for i in arr:
    print (rx.sub('', i))
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/RCWDNn)